# Questions regarding windows volume licensing, how are software installations tracked? Are they?

Tags: windows, license

I have recently gotten a hold of a volume license key via one of my friends from his place of work, I would ideally like to be able to use it to install Windows on one of my computers. This computer would be one of my only computers running Windows (I prefer Linux but due to compatibility issues etc. It would be nice to have at least one Windows Install).

Now I'm wondering if volume license installations/usages can be tracked, I would really hate for me or him to get in trouble, and If they are how exactly that tracking system works.

If this is perhaps the wrong place to be asking such a question I do apologise.

Comment: VLK installs need to connect to a licensing server - which will be a) probably impossible for you to reach & b) likely audited, so they'll spot the rogue. If it fails to connect, the activation will time out.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help.